# split violinplot in seaborn with hue parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a `violinplot` using only the `y` and `hue` parameters in `seaborn` (`x` data variable is defined as None). Using a similar example as in the documentation I have done:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.violinplot(y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True)
```

And the resulting figure is not split according to the hue variable.

[image]

When the x variable is defined the plot is split. Is there any way to have a split plot in seaborn without x input?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Simply add a variable that is the same for all entries and use it as `x`:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips["all"] = ""
ax = sns.violinplot(x="all", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True)
ax.set_xlabel("")
```

[image]

Comment: This long article is not able to explain, what you have explained in 2 lines.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html